# No Such Method error when using recycle view and values from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, runtime-error

I created a project with recyclerview on a fragment activity. But when I executing this project shows an error like this. There had not any error at the time of recyclerview with values from app itself. But when I tried to retrieve values from firebase to app showing this error and activity closes at that time.
Anyone knows how to fix this error? Please help me. Advanced thanks

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Binder#execTransact(int,int,int,int)#exact
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findMethodExact(XposedHelpers.java:339)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:176)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:251)
    at com.phoneinfo.changerpro.hooks.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.phoneinfo.changerpro.hooks.MainHook.handleLoadPackage(Unknown Source)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage$Wrapper.handleLoadPackage(IXposedHookLoadPackage.java:34)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.call(XC_LoadPackage.java:61)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XCallback.callAll(XCallback.java:106)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge$1.beforeHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:234)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:1550)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(<Xposed>)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:163)
```

**My Code:**

```
public class DocterList extends Fragment {
private DatabaseReference dataref;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Doc> result;
private DocViewHolder adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_docter_list, container, false);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());
    dataref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Docters");
    result = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.docter_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Doc,DocViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Doc, DocViewHolder>(
            Doc.class,
            R.layout.view_docter,
            DocViewHolder.class,
            dataref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(DocViewHolder viewHolder, Doc model, int position) {
           viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setCity(model.getCity());

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
public static class DocViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textName,textPlace;
    public DocViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        textPlace= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        textName.setText(name);
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        textPlace.setText(city);
    }
}
```

}

**Model Doc class:**

```
public class Doc {
    String Name,City;

    public Doc() {
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Doc(String name, String city) {
        Name = name;
        City = city;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code. I think this is a problem related with Xposed Framework.

Comment: I included my code now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this stack trace from your personal test device or from a third-party user?

My estimate is this is from a third-party user, whose device is [rooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android)) and has [Xposed Framework](https://www.howtogeek.com/164634/forget-flashing-custom-roms-use-the-xposed-framework-to-tweak-your-android/) installed.

The said user is using an Xposed Module to try to "hook" into your app's function calls - Unfortunately due to an error in their hooking code, the app is crashing.

If yes, then this is no fault of your own or you app, and cannot be remedied by you.

Fix - If you control the device, you can temporarily disable all xposed modules (Or just the one particular module - `com.phoneinfo.changerpr...` that is leading to the crash.). Unrooting will probably not fix it, you need to disable the Xposed module (Or the entire Xposed Framework.).

Comment: Absolutly correct..My phone is rooted and installed xposed modules..This is the answer that i am waited for.. thanks..you are great..

Comment: Any solution to fix this without unroot.?

Comment: @Suhail - I have edited the answer to include the fix.
P.S. - please mark the answer as correct if it is :P